# How to detect that WP8.1 app launched on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I need to check OS version (WP 8.1 or W10) in my code of WP8.1 application. What better way to do this? May be reflection or some special API for this purpose?

Comment: WP8.1 probably won't be able to install the W10 app. If you create app with different configurations for platforms, maybe you can use preprocessor directives?

Comment: @Romasz I tested the my WP8.1 app on WM10 Emulator, it works. And some users already install my app on their W10 devices. I do not want to create different build configurations before creating special UWP version in the future. I want check version in code.

Comment: Ok, so you need only to check if WP8.1 runs on W10. First I thought about [this OSversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.operatingsystem), but as I've tested it returns 'WindowsPhone' for both operating systems.

Comment: @Romasz you are right, methods returns 'WindowsPhone' for both operating systems. Unfortunately I not found solution of my problem yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any other way to do this, so here's my approach.

The following property `IsWindows10` detects if a Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 app is running on a Windows 10 (including Windows 10 Mobile) device.

```
 #region IsWindows10

    static bool? _isWindows10;
    public static bool IsWindows10 => (_isWindows10 ?? (_isWindows10 = getIsWindows10Sync())).Value;

    static bool getIsWindows10Sync()
    {
        bool hasWindows81Property = typeof(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package).GetRuntimeProperty("DisplayName") != null;
        bool hasWindowsPhone81Property = typeof(Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation).GetRuntimeProperty("RawPixelsPerViewPixel") != null;

        bool isWindows10 = hasWindows81Property && hasWindowsPhone81Property;
        return isWindows10;
    }
 #endregion
```

**How does it work?**

In Windows 8.1 the `Package` class has a `DisplayName` property, which Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't have.
In Windows Phone 8.1 the `DisplayInformation` class has a `RawPixelsPerViewPixel` property, which Windows 8.1 doesn't have.
Windows 10 (including Mobile) has both properties. That's how we can detect which OS the app is running on.

Answer (score -1):

Try this  [System.Environment.OSVersion.Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.version%28v=VS.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Unfortunately WP8.1(XAML) not support property OSVersion in the class Environment.