# How can we detect Windows 10 in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

my app (developed in Windows Phone 8.1 RT environment) uses OpenFilePicker which allows me to choose image and capture an image, it works great however when I deployed this app on a Windows 10 device, this function just allowed me to pick an image from the library. I thought about a solution, writing a small code block which can help me to detect the version of the OS like this

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
//codes
#endif
```

But I don't know exactly what I need to do, so please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect that WP8.1 app launched on Windows 10 Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840624/how-to-detect-that-wp8-1-app-launched-on-windows-10-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this link:

[Windows Store Apps: Get OS Version, beginners tutorials (C#-XAML)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Windows-Store-Apps-Get-OS-a5de724b)

it purpose a simple solution to check is OS has Windows 10 features with reflection:

```
var analyticsInfoType = Type.GetType("Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime"); 
var versionInfoType = Type.GetType("Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsVersionInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime"); 

if (analyticsInfoType == null || versionInfoType == null) 
{ 
 // That's not Windows 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am not using PC right now but I will try, thanks!